# YouTube Disallowed File Type

Tags: video, youtube

I've recently upgraded my live site to 2.4.3-p2 and my development to 2.4.4.

On both sites I am now unable to add YouTube videos to my products. I was able to before. Images all work and Vimeo works fine but not YouTube.
When I input a YouTube Url it gets the video data but when I click "Save" it displays "Disallowed file type." below the Url.
I cannot find anyone else with this issue. I was able to add videos previously.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you configure Integrate YouTube API key for magento 2. For more think check below link. Below link follow all steps. Let me know if any query.

https://meetanshi.com/blog/add-youtube-videos-in-magento-2-product-pages/

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: The API key is correctly configured. As mentioned, this worked fine before upgrade to  2.4.3-p2 & 2.4.4.